# How to namespace/target a component input variable

Tags: angular, angular-material

Given the following

- `mat-button` directive responds to a `disabled` attribute / input
- `matTooltip` directive responds to a `disabled` attribute / input

Is it possible to create a material button element that is disabled, but has a non-disabled tooltip associated with it? i.e. is it possible to namespace / target a component input so that it only applies to the `mat-button` directive and not the `matTooltip` directive?

In the following example, both the button AND tooltip are disabled:

```
<button mat-button matTooltip="first enter email address" [disabled]=true>
  Next
</button>
```

I can't seem to disable just the button and not the tooltip. It's possible that this is a bug in the current `matTooltip` implementation.

Thanks!!

*Using angular 4.4.6 and material 2-beta.12*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to resolve input name conflicts except renaming the inputs.

You can use a helper element and split the component and directive so that they don't share the same host element:

```
<span matTooltip="first enter email address">
  <button mat-button  [disabled]=true>
    Next
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Apparently I need to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer